# Vandalizing own question due to bounty preventing deletion

Tags: discussion, questions, vandalism

In a question, the OP vandalized their own question, because they realized the question is invalid after they launched a bounty on the question.

This invalidated one or more existing answers. I'm very tempted to rollback the vandalizing edit, however I do not want to get into a rollback war.

On the other hand, the OP will likely delete the question after the bounty ends, so rolling back the "naughty" edit won't help much.

What would be the best course of action here?

Comment: The community can undelete it, but I wonder whether the question is of any use, if a high rep user is willing to delete it(probably because he's embarrassed of the question)

Comment: Now that the sole answer has an upvote, OP deletion isn't possible, as far as I know.

Comment: @halfer The (now 2) upvotes on the answer were all cast less than an hour ago, and this post is 2 hours old, so the answer had 0 upvotes at first.

Comment: @Ann: it would not surprise me. While I don't think people should vote based on a Meta-post, it is somewhat understandable that people use votes to stop people deleting their content in a way that deletes other peoples' content.

Answer (score 36):

1. Roll back
2. Post a comment explaining that even when deletion is not possible, the author is not allowed to vandalize posts
3. If OP gets into a rollback war with you, flag and ask mods to lock the post
4. If you agree the question should be deleted and the author doesn't delete it themselves then if the post ever becomes eligible for deletion, cast a delete vote